# Git push to remote repo has no effects

Tags: git, version-control, push, git-clone, pull

I have set up a repo at a server of mine like this:

```
> git init 
> git config --local receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead
> git add *
> git commit -m "Init Git"
```

This is how I have pulled the repo, made some changes and pushed it back to the server:

```
> git clone ssh://user:password@host.com/backend
> git add *
> git commit -m "First Push"
> git push origin master
```

That all goes through without any problems!

If I now check the branches and logs I get on my server as well on my computer this:

```
> git log
commit 8f69afeffae2c44d6952dbb753a003deea2fbe2a
Author: Mac 
Date:   Thu Jun 21 17:47:19 2018 +0200

    First Push

commit 787c90ee79a4f3da207a57fcca552ebb7087294c
Author: Server 
Date:   Thu Jun 21 17:43:46 2018 +0200

    Init Git

> git branch -v
> * master 8f69afe First Push
```

That means both my computer as well as the server are up to date and should contain the same files. However, this is not true...

I have edited a file on my computer before I have committed it and pushed it back to the server with the message "First Push". The changes are made on my computer but I don't see the changes on my server.. How can that be if the server has received the push and says that he is on the same branch?

Do I have to checkout? How can I update the repo on the server as well?

If I pull the repo again to my computer, it says "All files are up to date"!

Kind regards and Thank You!

Comment: How do you inspect the changes on the server? Servers usually run the `--bare` repository with no working copy.

Comment: Via FTP and also I can see that the website hasn't changed...

Comment: I just have tried to do this but now after I have inited the repo and want to add files, I get "fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree"

Comment: I have changed the git repo on my server to a git bare repo. Still the same problem.. Hasn't changed anything... I still can see that the repo on the server is on the newest commit, but the changes are not made..

Comment: How do you check the changes in a bare repo?

Comment: As I said: Via FTP and they should also take effect on the website...

Comment: Can you show how you check via FTP? What code generates the website?

Comment: I just edit the index.php from `echo "Hello World";` to `echo "Good Morning";` and nothing changes.. not on the website as well as in the file via FTP

Comment: Oh, so you're using git for deployment! It's a different kind of server. You shouldn't push to it, you should pull from a git server there instead.

Comment: @Jan Did the answer help you solve the problem? If yes, can you mark the answer. And it will also benefit others who meet similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

> How can that be if the server has received the push and says that he
>   is on the same branch?

You puhed the local `master` branch to remote `master` branch (same branch in remote).

To push local branch to the branch of git server, it’s specified by the the command `git push origin master`. The command is  equal with `git push origin <localbranch>:master`. That means you pushed the local `master` branch to remote `master` branch.

And to trouble the reason why local `master` branch version is different from remote `master` branch version, you can check with below aspects:

#### 1.   Check if local branch has un-committed changes

Use the command `git status` to check if the working tree is clean. If there has uncommitted changes, you should commit and push the changes to remote.

#### 2.   Check the difference between local master branch and remote master branch

Use below commands to check the file differences between local master and remote master branch:

```
git fetch origin
git diff master origin/master
```

#### 3.   Check the diff logs between local master branch and remote master branch

Use below commands to check the diff logs between local master branch and remote master branch:

```
git log master..origin/master --oneline
git log origin/master..master --oneline
```